# Assign Variable values in to inner html Spring MVC tag values

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I would request your help to assign values to a hidden form field using Spring MVC tags, however its not taking the variable value, rather its taking the variable as text, I am new to this technology, so not too sure where I am going wrong.

```
var subEnt = $("#selEntity").val(); //gets data from dynamic dropdown within the form
var inpmarkup='<form:hidden path="bypassModel.selectedEntities" value="' +subEnt+ '"/>'; //create the inner html

$("table tbody").append(inpmarkup); //add the inner html to the DOM
console.log("inpmarkup=> ",inpmarkup); //console log the inpmarkup
```

In the console window, when I did console.log for the inpmarkup, it gives me

```
inpmarkup=>  <input id="selectedEntities" name="selectedEntities" value=" +subEnt+ " type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Also when the see the DOM, it shows me the below:

```
<input id="selectedEntities" name="selectedEntities" value=" +subEnt+ " type="hidden">
```

I would really appreciate your kind help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if `$("#selEntity").val();` has any value ? Also above code works fine .Here, is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9q62yo0u/

Comment: Yes, the $("#selEntity").val() is getting value, the console.log prints it, and when I add it to a <td> element within a table its displaying the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Swati and BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is ' makes the literal pass of its content, its probably a weird read of your code, try adding spaces between subEnt or try this:

`var inpmarkup='<form:hidden path="bypassModel.selectedEntities" value='+'"'+ subEnt +'"'+'/>'; //create the inner html`

Comment: I tried using this: var inpmarkup='<form:hidden path="bypassModel.selectedEntities" value='+'"'+ subEnt +'"'+'/>'; //create the inner html, however its throwing an error saying Unterminated [&lt;form:hidden] tag

Comment: try creating a var to put that long string first, then use concat() method to add subEnt and then concat() the " and the closing tag

Comment: I already tried using concat, still it does not work. The interesting thing is that when I run the same javascript code using node, same string works and its able to recognize the variable value. I will continue to challenge myself and try to put up a answer if I find any. Thanks a lot for your help Sergio, appreciate it.